# Does Varnish support IPv6?

Tags: ip, ipv6, varnish

Their [specification draft](http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VarnishSpecDraft) says they should on section 3.2.1. Are we there yet? Has anyone used Varnish with IPv6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/reference/varnishd.html?highlight=ipv6  This is from the documentation of varnish, and answers your question: yes, varnish has IPv6 support.

Comment: Varnish2 is not completely ipv6-ready, hardcoded IPs in the backend definition failed for me - ref https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/832 - this has been fixed in varnish3 though.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but read of people using Varnish as a dual-stack front-end for an IPv4-only web server. So, it should be possible.